# Have `purrr::pmap()` ignore extra columns?

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to use `purrr::pmap()` to map a function over columns of a data frame by name.

However, I noticed that with `pmap`, the data frame must contain columns that match the names in the function **and cannot contain other columns**. For example, the first `pmap()` call below fails, but the second works, where I filter to the needed columns.

Is there a way to have `pmap()` ignore the extra columns? Or this there a better way to do this type of thing?

```
library(tidyverse)

# Test data
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
df <- tibble(a = runif(5),
             b = runif(5),
             c = runif(5),
             d = runif(5))

f <- function(a, b, d) a+b+d
```

```
# Doesn't work
pmap(df, f)
```

```
Error in .f(a = .l[[1L]][[i]], b = .l[[2L]][[i]], c = .l[[3L]][[i]], d = .l[[4L]][[i]],  : 
  unused argument (c = .l[[3]][[i]])
```

```
# This works
pmap(df[c("a", "b", "d")], f)
```

Comment: if you known the positions of the columns you can use that in a lambda-style formula: `pmap(df, ~ ..1 + ..2 + ..4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `select` the columns based on the argument values in the function

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
pmap(df %>% 
     select(any_of(names(as.list(args(f))))), f)
[[1]]
[1] 1.232959

[[2]]
[1] 1.562498

[[3]]
[1] 1.343455

[[4]]
[1] 1.762373

[[5]]
[1] 2.351586
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
 library(tidyverse)

# Test data
df <- tibble(a = runif(5),
             b = runif(5),
             c = runif(5),
             d = runif(5))

f <- function(...) {
   l <- list(...)
   with(l, a+b+d) 
}
pmap(df, f)
```

alternatively:

```
f <- function(...) {
   list2env(list(...), environment())
   a+b+d 
}
```